# How does a third party website know which Facebook user just logged in?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, response

I am trying a set up a login with Facebook, and it works – but how do I know which Facebook user logged in? Does the Facebook API return something? I could not find anything useful in the responses.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When you send a request facebook provides a user id that can be stored in your database and used for whenever to compare